# Reduce read usage on Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

We are currently using the free tier on Firebase, with a quota of 50k read and 20k write operations.

With around 100 daily users, we are already over quota on the read operations. The structure of the `Firestore` is the following:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- steps (collection)
    |   |
    |   --- 20191206 (document)
    |       |
    |       --- users (collection)
    |           |
    |           --- 08yzYycNqYMZw7kdeGBNV9jcg1G2 (document)
    |               |
    |               --- country: "FR"
    |               |
    |               --- name: "florian"
    |               |
    |               --- steps: 24
    |               |
    |               --- updated_at: "2019-12-05T20:25:05Z"
```

The application displays a list of users ordered by their number of steps.

So as a simple calculation, at every app launch, if `x` equals the number of user entries stored in the `users` collection, `x+1` documents should be read representing `x+1` read operations. For 100 users opening the app and 100 users entries, It should be already 10100 read operations (~20% of the daily quota).

Am I right on my read operation calculations? (if 1 read operation = 1 read document).

On the other hand, is there a way to optimize the Firestore structure to reduce the number of document read?

We currently have a patch that use the `.limit()` operation to avoid selecting all the entries to free some read operation but it's not a permanent solution here.

Having all the step data in one document also seems a bad solution since each document must have a size < 1MB. It can be a solution for some time but will also be a limitation if the user base is growing.

Thank you for your suggestions on this.

---

## EDIT 2019/12/06 #1

Here are the queries (for iOS here) used on the steps collection.

- fetch leaderboard for a specific time frame (ex: daily = 20191206, monthly = 201912)

```
db
    .collection("steps")
    .document(date.string)
    .collection("users")
    .whereField("steps", isGreaterThan: 0)
    .order(by: "steps", descending: true)
    .getDocuments { }
```

- update user steps for a specific time frame

```
db
    .collection("steps")
    .document(date.string)
    .collection("users")
    .document(uid)
    .setData([
        "steps": steps,
        "name": name,
        "country": country,
        "updated_at": Date.NowISO8601,
    ])
```

Comment: We usually structure the database according to the queries we want to perform. If you need a better schema, tell us what are the queries you want to perform.

Comment: Hi and thank you @AlexMamo. question updated

Comment: If you have 100 users, it's time to start thinking about being on payment plan to support those active users.  The free tier is to support development, not production.

Comment: Seeing your queries, I think you should go ahead with Doug's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Firebase official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), you are charged per document read, write and delete. So your calculations seem okay.

Based on the number of users, you might need to consider moving to a paid plan. Possibly the [Flame Plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

However, here is a suggestion to minimize the charges:

Since you are talking about something like a leader-board based on number of steps, I assume that you don't really need updates every few seconds.

What I would do, is make the queries once every specific time-frame and store the values in [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing) where you are charged for storage size instead of read/writes (you get 5GB/month free). Then let your app get the data from Cloud Storage.

This way you will have a constant amount of reads no matter of the number of users you have.

> For example:
>
> 100 users & updating the leader-board once every 10 mins
>
> 100 x (24x60 / 10) = **14.4K reads/day**

Depending on your use-case, you might be able to follow a similar logic for writes as well.